# Running command line commands within PyCharm

Tags: python, command-line, pycharm

Hi I am using Python and have never really used it before. I have some commands sent to me that I need to run in the terminal. Basically:

```
python Test.py GET /feeds
```

I am using PyCharm and I was wondering if there was a way to run these same commands from within that IDE?

Comment: Why don't you just find the location of your project and execute from the command line?

Comment: you may also consider https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/interactive-console.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Press Alt+F12 to open terminal within PyCharm, then write in the command you wish to run and press enter.

In your case:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>
2. Type `python Test.py GET /feeds`
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Tools/Add New Bash Console, or clicking on the Terminal icon, on Mac version 2019.1.4.  (Neither of them integrating usefully with PyCharm in my case, and with inferior text handling—e.g. drag&drop is broken.)

Comment: Is there a shortcut to run a line from your script in the terminal? Instead of typing/pasting into terminal?