# How can I properly install spaCy en_core_web_sm on PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, spacy

I have been trying to experiment with spaCy and trying to get the en_core_web_sm model with the PyCharm Terminal. I keep getting an error about the syntax. What is the correct way to install this model with the PyCharm terminal?

Comment: What have you tried? `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` should do it.

Comment: It says that it is a syntax error. Is there anything else I need to add?

Comment: What is the exact error output you are getting? Are you typing in the Python console or the PyCharm terminal?

Comment: It is the Python console in PyCharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `python -m spacy download ...` is not Python, it is a command to be executed in the shell, which is why you get a syntax error. To run shell commands in PyCharm push Alt+F12 ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570058/running-command-line-commands-within-pycharm#:%7E:text=Press%20Alt%2BF12%20to%20open,Press%20Alt%20%2B%20F12)).

Comment: @the_spider_collector the Python console and the PyCharm terminal emulator are two different things, and it seems you confused them—hopefully this answer solved it for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was really far off there :)

Comment: No worries, a lot of people get confused about that at first. Note that your question was probably closed because you did not paste the full text of the error. I understood what you meant because I've seen this before, but in general you should post the full error text so other people can help you more easily.